# TestNG error in IntelliJ "It is strongly recommended to add "<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >" at the top of your file"

Tags: intellij-idea, testng

I already changed the below items since I saw this-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57299606/testng-by-default-disables-loading-dtd-from-unsecure-urls

1. Run/Debug configurations both class&method in both TESTNG and TESTNG Template vm option: -ea -Dtestng.dtd.http=true
2. testng.xml, and even I deleted the first line and follow the error message to put <!DECOTYPE ..... to the first line, it still failed

I still encounter this error.
Could anyone please help with this, please?

[image: testng.xml]

[image: Run/Debug_Configurations]

Comment: Please tell why do you think that NoClassDefFoundError is connected with TestNG warning?

Comment: @OlgaKlisho Thanks a lot for the heads up. I found my external library was not completed. after adding the "libs" folder under selenium-java-3.141.59 with okhttp-3.11.0.jar and okio-1.14.0.jar, it worked fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The external library was not completed.
After adding the "libs" folder under selenium-java-3.141.59 with okhttp-3.11.0.jar and okio-1.14.0.jar, it worked fine!
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to add `-Dtestng.dtd.http=true` if you are going to create your own *testng.xml* file with `https` for IntelliJ **Run/Debug Configurations** to use. You were seeing the error message because IntelliJ did not use your *testng.xml* file. By default IntelliJ generates a *.xml* file for TestNG configurations, which has a path like this *C:/User/<your name>/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.2/temp-testng-customsuite.xml*. You however cannot overwrite it because it is regenerated every time a TestNG configuration runs. IntelliJ's TestNG plugin is currently unable to dynamically generate the *.xml* with correct protocol, i.e. `http` vs `https` because of the concern for backward compatibility. Please see this [commit](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/commit/74e1e46ad6fbdd0b8bcd34d6e03532d7b091383d#diff-9b4d43dbc051c4201a75c1a4375264f40dc828d44ab46f75711fa8c4bb6eb848R171) for more details.

To use your own *testng.xml*, you need to change the **Test kind** of your TestNG configuration to **Suite**, then put/select the path of your *testng.xml* to be the value of **Suite** and apply. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39818068/4942835) also illustrates the above steps with images.

Last but not least, although the wording of the TestNG warning is strong, it is unlikely to be the cause of the `NoClassDefFoundError` in your screenshot. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64877914/4942835) is the answer for fixing that `NoClassDefFoundError`.